# How can I generate a large ndarray with the structure of a smaller one in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to construct a large matrix with the structure of a smaller one in python using numpy ndarrays, where the dimensions are dynamic variables within my problem.

For a simple test case, take the following code:

```
A = np.ones((2, 2))
B = np.zeros((2, 2))

matrix_structure = np.diag(np.ones(dimension-1), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(dimension-1), -1)
```

For a matrix dimension of 4, the matrix structure might look like the following:

```
[ 0 1 0 0 ]
[ 1 0 1 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 1 ]
[ 0 0 1 0 ]
```

with the desired final matrix being something like:

```
[ B A B B ]
[ A B A B ]
[ B A B A ]
[ B B A B ]
```

where A and B are the smaller submatrices.

I'm stuck on how to make that step - the function np.block() would do what I want, if I could figure out how to pass an appropriate array.

Is there a way to generate and then pass a multi-dimensional list of variable names, which then would pull the appropriate variable? Or am I just barking up the wrong tree here?

Edit:

Just for clarification, the final matrix (if A and B  are 2x2) would look something like:

```
[ 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ]
[ 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ]
[ 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ]
```

ie. the same structure, but composed of the smaller submatrices. The simple ones/zeros submatrices are just being used for illustration purposes.

Comment: so, just put the matrices A in the correct spots using a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive approach would be to use [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy-block):

```py
np.block([[B, A, B, B],
          [A, B, A, B],
          [B, A, B, A],
          [B, B, A, B]]).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Incorporating `matrix_structure`:

```
ms = str(np.where(matrix_structure.astype(bool), "A", "B").tolist()).replace("'A'", "A").replace("'B'", "B")
np.block(eval(ms)).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

There is likely a better way than using `eval`, but it might give you an idea.

Comment: This is essentially exactly what I was going for, thank you! There might be a cleaner way, but this will definitely work for what I need it for ^^

Answer (score 1):

Make a bigger matrix of zeros,
Then add two smaller identity matrices in the correct position.

```
import numpy as np
dimension = 3
C = np.zeros((dimension+1, dimension+1))
C[:dimension,1:dimension+1] += np.eye(dimension)
C[1:dimension+1,:dimension] += np.eye(dimension)
print(C)

[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is quite what I was going for - I've edited the original post with a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can fancy index from subarrays *A*,*B* with a flattened *matrix_structure* and reshape to your desired result

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((2, 2))
B = np.zeros((2, 2))
matrix_structure = np.diag(np.ones(dimension-1), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(dimension-1), -1)

(np.stack([B,A])[matrix_structure.astype('int').flatten()]
   .reshape(matrix_structure.shape + A.shape)
   .swapaxes(1,2)
   .reshape(matrix_structure.shape[0]*A.shape[0], -1))
```

Output

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```